# How app retrieve data from server in small chunks?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am taking example of tinder here.In this app,it displays people present nearby me.
I want to know,if I am executing a query to get all the people nearby me then there will be a ton of data.Then how these websites,apps able to get data in small chunks?
Do they have to develop some logic to get data in pieces or are their any functionality provided by the predefined libraries in php or java etc.

I know it's very childish question but I have just started working for an online app and I want to know about this.
Thanks

Comment: This might not be a sutaible question for SO https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but *when site have really large amount of data, it displays that data in small segments of records*. This is called pagination.

Almost whatever software program interacts with database would provide you support for pagination. Below are some examples:

1. MySQL provides `LIMIT` query that you can use to fetch data in chunks

   ```
   SELECT * FROM city LIMIT 15, 10;
   ```

   it says `return only 10 records, start on record 16 (OFFSET 15)`. Similarly to get the next 10 records, you would change this query to

   ```
   SELECT * FROM city LIMIT 25, 10;
   ```
2. Hibernate's `criteria` have them concept of pagination

   ```
   Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
   criteria.setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
   criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
   ```
3. `dirPagination` is a pagination solutions for Angular

   ```
   <ul>
       <li dir-paginate="branch in branches | itemsPerPage: 10" pagination-id="branch">{{ customer.name }}</li>
   </ul>
   ```